# Splashscreen created with splashscreen plugin for cordova does not appear in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio-cordova, splash-screen

i added the splashscreen plugin in version 4.0.1 to my cordova project in VS2015. But the splashscreen doesn't appear, neither in android nor in ios simulator. What am i doing wrong?
My config.xml looks like this:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<platform name="android">
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
<splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version="4.0.1" />
```

I also tried to add `navigator.splashscreen.show()` to a deviceready eventListener but it's still not working.

Comment: Could you please try remove the platform and uninstall the app in simulator and rebuild and run again? And also make sure you have the correct image you can generate Android splash image in [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems to be an issue due to the Ripple emulator. I found out that every other emulator shows the splashscreen as expected.